# What is riemann index size?

Tags: clojure, monitoring, metrics, riemann, riemann-dashboard

In the [Riemann stream processing server](https://riemann.io/api/index.html), when we look at the internal Riemann metrics there is a metric value "Riemann index size"? What causes this value to increase? Is it based on the number of transport listeners configured to accept events (TCP, UDP, graphite)?

Comment: Not sure, but you aren't talking about it: https://riemann.io/api/riemann.index.html?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the index in the riemann server that is pointed by those docs. I think "riemann index size" is one of the metrics generated by the [instrumentation-service](https://riemann.io/api/riemann.core.html#var-instrumentation-service).
What determines this index size? Is it a load of events coming in?